# C Program stop working (m[0] -> rows = i;)

Tags: c

my program stopped working... .
I don't know why the program stop working if someone can help me, I would be very grateful

```
struct Matrix {
    unsigned int rows, cols;
    double * elems;
};
```

and here the function

```
Errorcode matrix_loadFromFile (Matrix * m, char * mFileName) {
char c;
unsigned int i;
FILE *fp;

fp = fopen(mFileName, "r");
if(fp == NULL) {
    return ERR_FOPEN;
}else {
    i = matrix_getnumber(fp);
    if(i == 0) {
        return ERR_INVALID_ROWS;
    }else {
        m[0] -> rows = i; /**here the program stop working ...*/
    };
    i = matrix_getnumber(fp);
    if(i == 0) {
        return ERR_INVALID_COLS;
    }else {
        m[0] -> cols = i;
    };

    for(i = 0; i < (matrix_rows(m[0]) * matrix_cols(m[0])); ++i) {
        m[0] -> elems[i] = matrix_getnumber(fp);
    };

    c = fgetc(fp);
    if(c != EOF) {
        return ERR_TRAILING_CHARS;
    };

    fclose(fp);
}

return 0;
}
```

Delivery is tomorrow, so I have not much time :/

Comment: `m[0] -> rows = i;` --> `m->rows = i;`

Comment: matrix.c: In function 'matrix_loadFromFile':
matrix.c:246:6: error: request for member 'rows' in something not a structure or union
    m -> rows = i;
      ^

Comment: if You define `typedef struct Matrix *Matrix;`, `(*m)->rows = i;` : Show caller side code.

Comment: are you sure that you are receiving valid pointer address (m)?

Comment: How was parameter of `m`(`Matrix * m`) made?

Comment: Does this code even compile? `m[0]->rows = i;` should get a compiler error, since `m[0]` is not a pointer.

Comment: the code compile but the program stoped working `m[0] -> rows = i;`

Comment: What is the `typedef` for `Matrix`? In C you can't use a structure name as a type without something like `typedef struct Matrix Matrix`.

Comment: `typedef struct Matrix *Matrix;`

Comment: I think there is a problem in creating `m`. if it is not created outside the function, `*m = malloc(sizeof(**m));` is required at the beginning of the this function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate elems first, like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < (matrix_rows(m[0]) * matrix_cols(m[0])); ++i) {
    m[0] -> elems[i] = malloc(sizeof(double));
    m[0] -> elems[i] = matrix_getnumber(fp);
};
```

Comment: You're only allocating space for 1 double, but then you're assigning to the i'th element of it.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed!